# CodeDeploy of React app on EC2 not workin properly

Tags: node.js, jenkins, amazon-ec2, aws-codebuild, react-scripts

I am really struggling to get a React App deployed to EC2 using Jenkins & AWS CodeDeploy.
Every time, I start to deploy the code I get the following error:

```
    [stdout]> react-scripts start
    [stdout]
    [stderr]node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922
    [stderr] throw err;
    [stderr] ^
    [stderr]
    [stderr]Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/start'
    [stderr]Require stack:
    [stderr]- /vclms/frontend/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
    [stderr] at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:15)
    [stderr] at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:98:19)
    [stderr] at Object.<anonymous> (/vclms/frontend/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts:31:23)
    [stderr] at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    [stderr] at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    [stderr] at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    [stderr] at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    [stderr] at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    [stderr] at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
    [stderr] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    [stderr] requireStack: [ '/vclms/frontend/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts' ]
    [stderr]}
    [stderr]npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    [stderr]npm ERR! errno 1
    [stderr]npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
    [stderr]npm ERR! Exit status 1
    [stderr]npm ERR!
    [stderr]npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
    [stderr]npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    [stderr]
    [stderr]npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    [stderr]npm ERR! /home/ec2-user/.npm/_logs/2020-11-23T22_40_49_472Z-debug.log
```

My Appspec.yml looks like this:

```
    version: 0.0
    os: linux
    files:
      - source: /
        destination: /vclms/frontend
    hooks:
      BeforeInstall:
       - location: scripts/setup.sh
         runas: ec2-user
      ApplicationStart:
        - location: scripts/start.sh
          timeout: 300
          runas: ec2-user
```

Setup.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
 export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
 nvm install node
 nvm install-latest-npm
```

And start.sh like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#backend start
# python vclms/backend/manage.py runserver 2>&1 &

#frontend start
whoami
whereis node
which node
whereis npm
which npm

cd /vclms/frontend

npm start
```

BTW: The file node_modules/.bin/react-scripts exists.

Any ideas what is failing here? I have no real clue where too look after some hours of search...

Best regards,
Max

Comment: Have you tried deleting `node_modules` and re-running `npm i`?